# how to achieve {0} in struts2 Field validation message

Tags: struts2

How to achieve parameterized message in struts2.
in actioname-validation.xml i have

```
<field name="family.familyName">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message key="common.required">
                <argo key="common.family" />
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
```

resource file i have,

```
common.required = {0} is required.
common.family = Family
```

some thing like this i tried. how to achive this?

Comment: this one would be the preferred way to do it against Pat's solution although both are helpful. JoseK's method would ensure that you could use the same again in an action class in exactly the same format to add an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/struts2-validation-example-struts-2-validation/) explains how to do what you want.  The gist of it is that you'd define your validation rule as follows:

```
<field name="family.familyName">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message key="common.required"/>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

And then in your .properties file, you'd have the following:

```
common.required = ${getText(fieldName)} is required.
family.familyName = Family
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. family.familyName i can't use. because in some other places i have to use something like, product.family.familyName, that time i have to define one more attribute.

Answer (score 2):

It gives me, what i expected

```
<field name="family.familyName">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>
                ${getText("requiredstring", {getText("common.family")})}
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
```

Application Resources,

```
requiredstring = {0} is required.
common.family = Family
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be also resolved as follows

```
<field name="family.familyName">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message key="common.required">
                <param name="1">getText('common.family')</param>
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
```